# Why laravel doesn't fire related model event?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a company and an address models. The relationship is 1-1. To simplify I'll omit the code with repositories.

In the company model I have such mutator:

```
public function setAddressAttribute($value)
{
    $this->address()->update($value);
}
```

And when I update company I fill it with 'address' attribute which is an array of address attributes. The updating itself works fine.

In address model I have this:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saved(function($address)
        {
            dd('saved');
        });
    }
```

I've tried different events, like creating/updating, but they only works only if I create a new company with address like this:

```
$company->address()->save(new Address($attributes['address']));
```

In this case I can catch the event, but when I try to update address, in spite of the fact that it actually gets updated the event won't fire.

Basically I just need to geocode the address when I update it, and put lat/lon values.

Thanks

**update**
Actually I've noticed that no events are fired when I use update method. If I use save() instead, then everything's okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something both in the `creating` and `updating` method of an eloquent model, you can use the `saving` method. Try this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($address)
    {
        // inside here you can put your logic
        dd('Saving Address');
    });
}
```

Further Reading:
[Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events)

Comment: I tried this event too, nothing happens though the model gets updated